# Submit form without form id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to submit form using through Ajax call but I'm having trouble selecting the form. I don't want to use form ID because I'm having multiple forms and I need to setup one code for all

```js
$(".pay").on("click",function(){
  var form = $(this).closest(".card-body").find("form");
  //$(form).submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = $(form).serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url    : "php/pay.php",
    data: formData
  })
  .done(function(response) {
  })
  //});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card" >
  <div class="card-header">
    <h1>XXX</h1>  
  </div>
  <div class="card-body" >
    <form> 
      <input name="user" value="mat" type="hidden">
      <input name="id" value="12" type="hidden">
    </form>
    <button class="btn btn-success pay" value="pay">pay</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger decline" value="decline" >decline</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the intention that when they click pay, that the form is submitted?  Because right now you are create a new submit handler every time the person clicks the pay button, not actually submitting the form, or doing the ajax.

Comment: You should be able to just remove the submit handler, do just the ajax inside it, and it should work.

Comment: Also `.find` returns jQuery object, no need to make it Jquery object again, simple `form` will do instead of `$(form)`.. rather declare like `var $form = $(this).closest(".card-body").find("form")`

Comment: @Taplar I tried removing it but nothing is submitted.

Comment: Try putting the button tags inside the form tag.

Comment: @A.K. what exactly did you remove?  Please update your question to show the modified code.

Comment: @Taplar updated.

Comment: Also comment out the `e.preventDefault()`.  You may be having a syntax error if the `e` is not defined.  Otherwise this logic looks correct.

Comment: Rather than scooting up and down the DOM, you can use the old-school yet perfectly good trick for getting the form that a control belongs to, namely `this.form`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to add `form submit` code because you are preventing submit, so when will you click just fetch data from the form and call your `AJAX` service.

I added one console log where you can see your form data.

```js
$(".pay").on("click",function(){
  var form = $(this).closest(".card-body").find("form");
  var formData = $(form).serialize();
  console.log(formData);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url    : "php/pay.php",
    data: formData
  })
  .done(function(response) {});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h1>XXX</h1>  
  </div>
    <div class="card-body" >
      <form> 
        <input name="user" value="mat" type="hidden">
        <input name="id" value="12" type="hidden">
      </form>
      <button class="btn btn-success pay" value="pay">pay</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger decline" value="decline" >decline</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is creating submit handler everytime the button is clicked, all you want is to send ajax call onclick, so just do that part.

```
$(".pay").on("click",function(){
    var form = $(this).closest(".card-body").find("form");
    // below code is creating submit handler everytime the button is clicked
    $(form).submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = $(form).serialize();
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url    : "php/pay.php",
            data: formData
            })
        .done(function(response) {
        })
    });
});
```

Also .find returns jQuery object, no need to make it Jquery object again, simple form will do instead of `$(form)`.. rather declare like `var $form = $(this).closest(".card-body").find("form")`

Something like below, try

```
$(".pay").on("click",function(){
    var $form = $(this).closest(".card-body").find("form");
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = $form.serialize();
        submitForm(formData);
});

function submitForm(formData){
       $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url    : "php/pay.php",
            data: formData
            })
            .done(function(response) {
            })
}
```

I've created below sample to refer

```js
$(function() {
  $(".pay").on("click", function(e) {
    var $form = $(this).closest(".card-body").find("form");
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $form.serialize();
    console.log(formData)
    submitForm(formData);
  });

  function submitForm(formData) {
    alert("submitting form with " + formData)
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "php/pay.php",
        data: formData
      })
      .done(function(response) {})
  }

});
```

```css
.card {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h1>XXX</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <form>
        <input name="user" value="mat" type="hidden">
        <input name="id" value="12" type="hidden">
      </form>
      <button class="btn btn-success pay" value="pay">pay</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger decline" value="decline">decline</button>


    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h1>YYY</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <form>
        <input name="user2" value="mat2" type="hidden">
        <input name="id2" value="122" type="hidden">
      </form>
      <button class="btn btn-success pay" value="pay">pay2</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger decline" value="decline">decline2</button>


    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to reduce duplicating the code..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        Var action = $(this).action;
        Var method = $(this).method; 
        Var data = $(this).serialize();
         // perform ajax operation here with data, action and method
    }); 
});
```

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Erm.. Why not just put the two buttons inside the form, to avoid any confusion or off-chance that the script might trigger another one of the "multiple forms" and refer to the nameless form through the parent element instead, like?

html:

```
<form>
   <input name="user" value="mat" type="hidden">
   <input name="id" value="12" type="hidden">
   <button class="btn btn-success pay" value="pay">pay</button>
   <button class="btn btn-danger decline" value="decline">decline</button>
</form>
```

script:

```
$(function() {
   $(".pay").on("click", function(e) {
     var $form = $(this).parent();
     e.preventDefault();
     var formData = $form.serialize();
     submitForm(formData);
});
```